# How to persist javascript console.log in REST Web Services (by overloads)?

Tags: javascript, angular, web-services

I have a Angular 5 application with any javascript `console.log("...");` I want create and add a javascript file on top on my application that overloads all `console.log("...");` with a POST function to a Web Services.

If my classic application log this:

```
console.log("start");
console.log("error");
console.log("stop");
```

I want my Angular5 application to process 3 asynchone POST requests to my Web Services. Example:

```
POST {"user": "foo", "log": "start"}
POST {"user": "foo", "log": "error"}
POST {"user": "foo", "log": "stop"}
```

**Note:** The user in the body is just an example because the final version uses a Json Web Token in the header.

**Is there a library to do this because it seems like a basic feature?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about replacing the default log function.

```js
(function() {
  var oldLog = console.log;
  console.log = function(msg) {
    oldLog.apply(console, arguments);
    alert(msg);
  }
})()


console.log("test")
```